# How can I launch different jar files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I get tired of renaming/copying/backing up various JARs when trying out snapshots. I haven't been able to find anything to help me bypass this renaming issue. Can I get Minecraft to launch different JARs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [MultiMC](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1000645-multimc-31-windows-linux-mac/), it works on Windows, OSX and Linux and allows you to run many instances of Minecraft from a single launcher.

It even allows you to automatically install mods to individual instances and have different save files for different versions.

Comment: Ooh, that's interesting. For now MagicLauncher works fine for me, but I may check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, apparently Magic Launcher can do this!

http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-099-mods-options-news/